# document.getSelection() display problem when click on the selected text

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).mouseup(function(){
 console.log(window.getSelection());
 console.log(window.getSelection().type);
});
```

Console when I've just selected some text and after clicking on the selected part of the text[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyOEF.png)

In the array "type":Caret, when I called window.getSelection().type it shows "Range"

Why it happened and how to get "Caret" when I clicked on the selected text?

There is no problem when I clicked on the unselected part of the text, I have "Caret" in the console

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO, please do take the time to read the [tour] and [ask] page.  Please provide a complete snippet that demonstrates your issue, see [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
  <head><title>Get Text when click on text</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>text content1...</h3>
    <h3>text content2...</h3>
    <h3>text content3...</h3>
    <script>
    $(document).on('click', function(event){
       console.log(window.getSelection());
      console.log(window.getSelection().type);
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's the same

If you'll try to click on the selected part of the text it'll be "Range" in the second stroke in console

In the first one it'll be "Caret"